# Fiddler blocks some HTTPS connections like Dropbox

Tags: web-services, dropbox, fiddler

I work on a project which make ajax query to a webservice so I use fiddler to see JSON responses.

But I have encounter troubles using Fiddler. When I launch it on my laptop, Dropbox can't synchronize my files anymore but I can debug my ajax requests. The real problem is when I use Fiddler on my desktop computer, all my requests to my WebService are blocked. My WebService runs on localhost.

I don't understand how it works, can you help me?

Answer (score 13):

Dropbox connections don't work because that application uses a feature called "Certificate Pinning" that reject's Fiddler's HTTPS interception certificate. Why this happens is discussed in the Fiddler book, but [you can configure Fiddler not to decrypt dropbox.exe's connections](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/httpfiddler/1A8Aks8ymPY/ZalTbWW0DV4J) which resolves the issue.

> To avoid blocking DropBox App traffic while Fiddler is running, you can use Tools > Fiddler Options > HTTPS to either only decrypt Browser traffic or you can configure Fiddler not to decrypt traffic to *.dropbox.com.

[image]

The issue with your "WebService" is almost certainly completely unrelated. You need to be far more specific for anyone to help: What is the client? What is the service written in? What do you see in Fiddler when this happens?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
My Web Service is built in C#. I make requests to an other webservice (www.flexmail.eu). It run on localhost and also my ajax script. When I call a method, in Fiddler I see -1 in the body column. I'm not at home so I can't be more specific for now.